# How to send date with gremlin javascript

Tags: javascript, date, gremlin

I think I'm missing something about the new javascript [gremlin client](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/tree/master/gremlin-javascript/src/main/javascript/gremlin-javascript).
I can't find any way to send any kind onf date from my script to the database.

Code example :

```js
import { P } from 'gremlin/lib/process/traversal':
import g from '../path/to/my/gremlin/client';

const myFunction = id => g.V(id).has('some_date', P.gte(new Date())
```

In this code example I send a javascript date object. I tried a formated string, a timetamp, a stringified timestamp, and one exotical things. 
And I always end up wwith an error like this one :

```
Error: Server error: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Date (500)
```

Or this one when I try with a number

```
Error: Server error: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.util.Date (500)
```

Is there anything I can do ?

Regards,

F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest storing your `Date` as a `String` in your graph using ISO-8601 format. Then you should have no type transformation problems from Javascript as you'll just be sending strings in your Gremlin.

You have to be somewhat aware of the data types you have in your graph versus the ones you have in the target programming language you're using. Unfortunately, there aren't always one-to-one mappings to all the possible types that can be stored in a Java-based graph database (e.g. [javax.time.*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)). For the most portable code and data, try to stick to the primitive types.

Comment: The problem is that I already have a janusgrpah instance, running since more than year now, that can't be "upgraded" right now. I've been using the previous JavaScript driver from jbmusso for more than 2 years now without this kind of error. Does that mean that I can't upgrade my JavaScript gremlin client to the latest version?

Comment: unless this gets done https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-1959 or this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-2001 or a serializer for `Date` is added http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.3.3/dev/io/#_date_2 i can't think of another way to make it work. surprised we don't support `Date` as it is in the standard types. don't know the reasoning for that (if there is any) - will probably create an issue.

Comment: just added a fix for future versions - https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/commit/db46c0f67fb1f93b9ea76032dbd2a852c24effd4

Comment: Thanks a lot ! U rock !